# How to pass boolean keyword argument along with the use of "Include" template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% include "example.html" with name="John" hide_last_name=True %}
```

Basically, I am trying to include "example.html" as a sub-template in my main template. Additional context is provided with the mean of passing the keyword arguments `name` and `hide_last_name`. While the django template system has no trouble recognize `name`, it somehow just can't recognize `hide_last_name`. I suspect the use of boolean keyword argument in `Include` tag is now allowed but then I can't find anywhere in the official docs mentions that. Please help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** This answer applies to old versions of Django. See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837828/1526703) for Django >=1.5

Django template would treat the `True` as a variable and try to find it in context.
You could either use non-empty string to represent the true value or assign the true value to the `True` in context, for example through `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
def common_vars(request):
    return {
        'True': True,
        'False': False,
        'newline': '\n',
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Was suspecting that but couldn't be sure. Thanks for confirming that.

Answer (score 15):

**For Django <= 1.4.x**

As said before, Django tries to find a variable named "True".
The simplest way to handle this is to use an integer value, which will not be evaluated.

You could write in the includer template

```
{% include "example.html" with show_last_name=1 %}
```

and in the included template

```
John
{% if show_last_name %}
    Doe
{% endif %}
```

**For Django >= 1.5**

You can use True and False in templates, so this is no longer a issue

Answer (score 2):

In django 1.5 you can use True in django templates as per their [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#minor-features).

And if you are working on earlier versions you would have to go for what @okm suggested!